# Spring Boot - Encrypt JSON data

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

In our application we have to encrypt/decrypt the Json property values (not the property name) for each request and response.
Example,
   `{"userName":"encrypted value", "email":"encrypted value"}`

We use Sprint boot 1.3 and we are using **@RequestBody** and **@ResponseBody** annotations to bind the request json with the object and serialise the response object as JSON.

We **don't** want to call encrypt/decrypt method in our each controller method. Is there any way we can instruct sprint to decrypt the json values before binding with the request object? Similarly, to encrypt the response object field values before converting them to json? Or customising Jackson may help us?

Thanks!

Comment: Build a custom client and do it there before call the service ..

Comment: What about implementing decrypt in getter and encrypt in setter?

Comment: Wouldn't breaking into, or extending AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter be more specific as this is where the json response is built, and the last point before it is flushed?

Comment: Have you found the solution? I am facing the same problem and @eparvan 's answer is irrelevant!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can write your own http message converter. Since you are using spring boot it would be quite easy: just extend your custom converter from `AbstractHttpMessageConverter` and mark the class with `@Component` annotation.

From [spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-responsebody-rendering):

> You can contribute additional converters by simply adding beans of that type in a Spring Boot context. If a bean you add is of a type that would have been included by default anyway (like MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter for JSON conversions) then it will replace the default value.

And here is a simple example:

```
@Component
public class Converter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<Object> {

    public static final Charset DEFAULT_CHARSET = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

    @Inject
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public Converter(){
        super(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8,
            new MediaType("application", "*+json", DEFAULT_CHARSET));
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object readInternal(Class<? extends Object> clazz,
                                  HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
        return objectMapper.readValue(decrypt(inputMessage.getBody()), clazz);
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeInternal(Object o, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
        outputMessage.getBody().write(encrypt(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(o)));
    }

    private InputStream decrypt(InputStream inputStream){
        // do your decryption here 
        return inputStream;
    }

    private byte[] encrypt(byte[] bytesToEncrypt){
        // do your encryption here 
        return bytesToEncrypt;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work if the whole json is encrypted. But in our case, only the json property values will be encrypted.

Comment: It's up to you to decide how to implement `encrypt` and `decrypt` methods. I think you may use `JsonNode` to iterate through all json object values in order to encrypt/decrypt them.

Comment: @eparvan what if the client is sending me a key in the request (in header), and I need to encrypt the response with it? How can I propagate the header value from `readInternal` to `writeInternal` method?

Comment: @Jezor use `inputMessage.getHeaders()` in `readInternal` and also same in `writeInternal`.

Comment: what about if few fields are encrypted and few  fields are not ? How can we differentiate ?

Comment: How to register this converter to be used when an HTTP request needs to be mapped to a object?, In other words, how to make sure that our custom converter is invoked to do the mapping?

Comment: Is there a way I can prevent this conversion for responses coming from the request to certain path? e.g: ('/authenticate')

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I used @eparvan 's answer and made few modifications.

1. Create a component that encrypts the JSON response and decrypt the request params from frontend.

I am fetching request params in encrypted format in "data" object something like this and also sending the encrypted response in the same way data object.

> reference response:
>   {"data":"requestOrResponseInEncryptedUsingPrivateKey"}

```
    @Component
    public class Converter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<Object> {

        private static final Charset DEFAULT_CHARSET = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

        @Autowired
        private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

        public Converter() {
            super(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,
                    new MediaType("application", "*+json", DEFAULT_CHARSET));
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected Object readInternal(Class<? extends Object> clazz,
                                      HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
            return objectMapper.readValue(decrypt(inputMessage.getBody()), clazz);
        }

        @Override
        protected void writeInternal(Object o, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
            outputMessage.getBody().write(encrypt(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(o)));
        }

        /**
         * requests params of any API
         *
         * @param inputStream inputStream
         * @return inputStream
         */
        private InputStream decrypt(InputStream inputStream) {
            //this is API request params
            StringBuilder requestParamString = new StringBuilder();
            try (Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
                    (inputStream, Charset.forName(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())))) {
                int c;
                while ((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
                    requestParamString.append((char) c);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                //replacing /n if available in request param json string

                //reference request: {"data":"thisisencryptedstringwithexpirytime"}

                JSONObject requestJsonObject = new
                        JSONObject(requestParamString.toString().replace("\n", ""));

                String decryptRequestString = EncryptDecrypt.decrypt(requestJsonObject.getString("data"));
                System.out.println("decryptRequestString: " + decryptRequestString);

                if (decryptRequestString != null) {
return new ByteArrayInputStream(decryptRequestString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                } else {
                    return inputStream;
                }
            } catch (JSONException err) {
                Log.d("Error", err.toString());
                return inputStream;
            }
        }

        /**
         * response of API
         *
         * @param bytesToEncrypt byte array of response
         * @return byte array of response
         */
        private byte[] encrypt(byte[] bytesToEncrypt) {
            // do your encryption here
            String apiJsonResponse = new String(bytesToEncrypt);

            String encryptedString = EncryptDecrypt.encrypt(apiJsonResponse);
            if (encryptedString != null) {
                //sending encoded json response in data object as follows

                //reference response: {"data":"thisisencryptedstringresponse"}

                Map<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                hashMap.put("data", encryptedString);
                JSONObject jsob = new JSONObject(hashMap);
                return jsob.toString().getBytes();
            } else
                return bytesToEncrypt;
        }
    }
```

2. Here is my EncryptDecrypt class where encryption and decryption is going on

   ```
   class EncryptDecrypt {

       static String encrypt(String value) {
           try {
               IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(Constants.Encryption.INIT_VECTOR.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
               SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new
                       SecretKeySpec("PRIVATE_KEY_FOR_ENCRYPTION_OR_DECRYPTION"
                       .getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "AES");

               Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
               cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

               byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
               byte[] original = Base64.getEncoder().encode(encrypted);
               return new String(original);
           } catch (Exception ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
           }
           return null;
       }

       static String decrypt(String encrypted) {
           try {
               IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(Constants.Encryption.INIT_VECTOR
                       .getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
               SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec("PRIVATE_KEY_FOR_ENCRYPTION_OR_DECRYPTION".
                       getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "AES");

               Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
               cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
               byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encrypted));
               return new String(original);
           } catch (Exception ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
           }

           return null;
       }
   ```

   }

And you're done!

Comment: Whenever you share some code please do share import statements also.

Comment: Is there a way I can prevent this conversion for responses coming from the request to certain path? e.g: ('/authenticate')

Comment: i have useed `readInternal` method issue with the encrypted request the error show     `-[AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:207]-Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'text/plain' not supported]` have you faced this issue ? have any solution for this ?

Comment: what do I import for Constants.Encryption.INIT_VECTOR ??