# Spring Boot - readMessageInternal of AbstractHttpMessageConverter implementation not getting invoked

Tags: spring-boot

Trying to write very simple http message converter to add encryption around request & respose.

Implemented rest controller and messageConverter. *writeInternal* does get invoked during response. **However *readInternal* does not get invoked when request is sent to the rest end point.**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpInputMessage;
import org.springframework.http.HttpOutputMessage;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.techm.bm.util.EncryptDecryptUtil;
@Component
public class MessageEncryptionConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<Object> {

@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

public MessageEncryptionConverter() {
    super(MediaType.ALL);
}

@Override
protected boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return true;
}

@Override
protected Object readInternal(Class<? extends Object> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage)
        throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
    return objectMapper.readValue(decrypt(inputMessage.getBody()), clazz);
}
@Override
protected void writeInternal(Object o, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage)
        throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
    outputMessage.getBody().write(encrypt(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(o)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code is for encryption and decryption of request and response body For overall Project to modify response body and request parameters. Please check this code is works for me

**For Request Encryption** refer `readInternal`

below is the **front-end or postman** request sending, you have to add encrypted request in Json formate

**Ex.{data : "+++++++++++++YOUR_ENCRYPTED_STRING++++++++++"}**

**For Response Descryption** refer `writeInternal`

sending back to your **front-end or postman request** response with encrypted string

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpInputMessage;
import org.springframework.http.HttpOutputMessage;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.techm.bm.util.EncryptDecryptUtil;

@Component
public class MessageEncryptionConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<Object> {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public MessageEncryptionConverter() {
        super(MediaType.ALL);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object readInternal(Class<? extends Object> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage)
            throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
        return objectMapper.readValue(decrypt(inputMessage.getBody()), clazz);
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeInternal(Object o, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage)
            throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
        outputMessage.getBody().write(encrypt(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(o)));
    }

// Convert request to input stream for sending to the controller
    private InputStream decrypt(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        //this is API request params
        Writer writer = new StringWriter();
        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        try {
            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
            int n;
            while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            logger.error("UnsupportedEncodingException" + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("IOException" + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            inputStream.close();
        }
        try {
            JSONObject requestJsonObject = new JSONObject(writer.toString().replace("\n", ""));
// Add your decryption method the object data will get your encrypted string data and return with string of your JSON object 
            String decryptRequestString = EncryptionUtils.decryptText(requestJsonObject.getString("data"));
            if (decryptRequestString != null) {
                return new ByteArrayInputStream(decryptRequestString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            } else {
                return inputStream;
            }
        } catch (JSONException err) {
            logger.error("Error" + err.toString());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | BadPaddingException | DigestException | InvalidKeyException
                | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | NoSuchPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            logger.info("NoSuchAlgorithmException | BadPaddingException | DigestException | InvalidKeyException | " +
                    "InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | NoSuchPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException:: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return inputStream;
    }

    private byte[] encrypt(Object obj) throws JsonProcessingException {
        // do your encryption here
        try {
            String stringFromObject = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
// Add your encryption method
            String encrypt = EncryptionUtils.encryptText(stringFromObject);
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(encrypt);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("Error While Encrypt data :: " + e.getMessage());
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(obj);
        }

    }
}
```

Reference code [Spring Boot - Encrypt JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40740771/spring-boot-encrypt-json-data/59135630#comment119308303_59135630)
Hope this code is working for you

Answer (score 0):

It is invoking if the request has body and "supports" method return ture